# How to get image size dyamically w/ mutliple instances?

Tags: javascript

I am using a FileReader to populate my images.

```
// i.e. .... e.target.result
```

If i set an image element source like this:

```
pic_upload_area.src = some_image;
```

I can get its dimensions like this:

```
width = pic_upload_area.clientWidth;
```

And things work fine.  However if I now reset it to a new image like this:

```
pic_upload_area.src = '';
pic_upload_area.src = new_image;
```

and once again get the image like this:

```
width = pic_upload_area.clientWidth;
```

I find that it still has the old image width, and the new image has been malformed to fit the old image's dimensions.

I find it strange that it works only on the first attempt.  How can I get `clientWidth` to update when I update the `.src` attribute of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to delete and recreate `pic_upload_area`. Once its dimensions are set, new image `src` will conform to the old dimensions.

Comment: @pure_code It's just the easiest. There's some cross-browser troubles with resetting width and height on an image without a library to help you out, and getting width and height of an unknown image is still much easier from a new uninitialized `img` than any other method that I'm aware of. Of course there are other approaches, like using canvas, manually resetting the attributes and CSS, etc. but why get into that?

Comment: I guess I found the `removeChild()` method had a strange interface...see below.

Comment: @pure_code Yes, using straight DOM calls the end run to parent can feel odd. With JQuery it would be: `$('#pic_upload_area').after("<img id='pic_upload_area'>").remove();`